# How To Convert Hex String to A Uint in Solidity ^8.0.0

Tags: solidity, string, uint256, hex, pure

I have this function that converts a unit to a hex string:

```
function uintToHexString(uint i) public pure returns (string memory) {
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    uint j = i;
    uint length;
    while (j != 0) {
        length++;
        j = j >> 4;
    }
    uint mask = 15;
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
    uint k = length;
    while (i != 0) {
        uint curr = (i & mask);
        bstr[--k] = curr > 9 ?
            bytes1(uint8(55 + curr)) :
            bytes1(uint8(48 + curr)); // 55 = 65 - 10
        i = i >> 4;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
```

The above function works as intended. For example, when I pass in the number 255 it returns the string "FF".

Now, I am having trouble creating a function that does the reverse- takes the string "FF" (or any hex string in general) and returns the corresponding uint value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Can probably be optimized for gas consumption but will get the job done.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract ConvertStuff {

    function numberFromAscII(bytes1 b) private pure returns (uint8 res) {
        if (b>="0" && b<="9") {
            return uint8(b) - uint8(bytes1("0"));
        } else if (b>="A" && b<="F") {
            return 10 + uint8(b) - uint8(bytes1("A"));
        } else if (b>="a" && b<="f") {
            return 10 + uint8(b) - uint8(bytes1("a"));
        }
        return uint8(b); // or return error ... 
    }

   

    function convertString(string memory str) public pure returns (uint256 value) {
        
        bytes memory b = bytes(str);
        uint256 number = 0;
        for(uint i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            number = number << 4; // or number = number * 16 
            number |= numberFromAscII(b[i]); // or number += numberFromAscII(b[i]);
        }
        return number; 
    }

}
```